# Is Enum the only way to show values for a Property as drop down list in the design time

Tags: c#, winforms, design-time

I know when I use `Enum` and put it as `Property` for class/UserControl, it will show/display it with drop down list like this:

[image]

But is this the only way to display available values like "drop down list"? Do we have other ways to do it?

**Edit:** The scope is Windows Form Application

For who didn't understand me

In that image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMank.png) where wrote "DataBase" is the `Name` of the `Property` in design time.

The values: `NotChoseYET`, `ChooseDataBase`, `ThereAlreadyDataBase` are values in Enum I created.

As you can see they displayed in a `DropDownList` in the design, so I want to ask if there are other ways to display like that without Enum?

Comment: You can use a converter that will take the enum value and return a "displayable" string.

Comment: what??? i misunderstand you

my question isn't convert any Enum to anything. I just wonder if there any control or any other way to show values like in the picture Except from using Enum

Comment: What kind of project is this?  WinForms, WPF, etc?

Comment: Windows Form Application

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Is that the only way to *automatically* do it? Probably. You can use any control you want though (Radio buttons come to mind), you'll just have to set some of it up yourself. Or is this due to it being in a DataGrid (not clear if it is from your picture)?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i ask if there other way to values like "DropDownList" in the designer/Property or only Enum can do it

if i use Enum and make values in that enum, when i make Property to this Enum, it display in "DropDownList".

so i ask if there other way to display values in "DropDownList" in designer without Enum

Comment: Are you asking if there is another control which displays values like `DropDownList` but isn't a `DropDownList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After tons of searches, I found what I had answered was only partially correct, so I would like to answer it again.

The answer to your question is a definite **NO**, we have some other way to show values on property as `DropDownList`. Like what I mentioned in my old answer, if values come from some kind of `Set`, or in other word it belongs to a **collection of values**, it will be displayed as a `DropDownList` **without any extra efforts** (because the `UITypeEditor` has been specified for them, you will understand this point later). Here are 3 examples:

- If a `Property` is a `bool`, in the designer it will show you a `DropDownList` contains `True` and `False`;

[image: drop down list with 2 values]

- If a `Property` is a `Font.Name`, in the designer it will show you a `DropDownList` with `SmallIcon`;

[image: drop down list with small icon]

- if a `Property` is a `Color`, in the designer it will show you **some** `DropDownList` encapsulated in a `TabControl`.

[image: tab control encapsulates drop down list]

From those "native" examples, you may realize a fact: we could somehow use some controls other than a simple `DropDownList` in the `Property Tab` during the design time. For example, a `Color` property gives a `TabControl` instead of a simple `DropDownList`, and a `Font.Name` property gives a customized `DropDownList`.

Yes, this is the second thing I am going to talk about. You are not only able to customize the items in the `DropDownList`, but also the `View` of that `Value Choosing Editor`.

However, this is **very tricky and non-trivial**. You are not recommended to do this unless it really adds value to your user control in the design time.

In short, you need to inherit from `UITypeEditor`, and override 2 functions:

`GetEditStyle()`, which

> indicates to the design environment which kind of user interface your UI type editor implements

and `EditValue()`, which

> establishes the interaction between the design environment and the user interface for editing your custom type

Then for your property which makes use of the `Editor`, you need to add `EditorAttribute` to it to specify the `Editor` used when selecting value of that property.

For better details, you are suggested to check this [MSDN walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx), which explains how to design a customized `Value Editor` in the design time.

Now back to the point where we left over. The native type, like `bool` and `Color`, has already bond to 
a `UITypeEditor`, thus no further working should be done.

---

Old Answer:

For properties, you need to choose a value from a kind of `Set`, and all elements in that `Set` will be displayed as `Items` in a `DropDownList` during design time. When you try to define the `Set`, `Enum` is one method to define them. Also, you can use `set of struct`, like `Color`. In other words, if you have a `Property` that returns `Color` (or other structs), during design time it will appear as a drop down list.

Comment: can you give me as example what do you mean "struct" "Set"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add items to a combobox control by using its .Items property:

```
  private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        // add items to the combobox
        // you can use any object. The .ToString() method will be used for displaying it
        cbxTest.Items.Add("This is test string " + i);
     }
  }
```

This will yield the following form:

[image]

Comment: i didnt mean in run-time, i mean in designer mode, when you choose property to control such as :font,back Color.

if there way to display properties like that (as you show) but in Designer, show it as properties

Comment: You can still use the .Items property then. Even in the designer.

Comment: i know that, but i didn't mean that.

look at that image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMank.png

that one property of control i made.
that open it in the design mode like combobox
that property is Enum

Comment: in that image(http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMank.png) where wrote "DataBase" is the Name of the Property
and the values: "NotChoseYET,ChooseDataBase,ThereAlreadyDataBase" are values in Enum i created.
you see in the design it show like DropDownList
so i ask if there other way to display like that without Enum

Comment: @WeSt he wants it to be done in the design time but not the run time

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question as I recently needed to do the same.
I posted a question ... which in the end I anwsered myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770017/wpf-designer-custom-properties-dropdown/45778910#45778910).

> In a nutshell: Implement a type converter
>   `GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)` to return
>   true and `GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)` to return
>   the `StandardValuesCollection` for the property type. Finally just
>   decorate the property like so:
>
> ```
> [TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
> public MyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
> ```
>
> The designer property window will now have a dropdown with valid values.