# WPF designer custom properties - dropdown

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer, custom-properties

I would like to have a drop down selection for a custom property on a User Control in WPF.
Everything works fine when I use an Enum as the property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Sample.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Sample : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    public Sample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DefaultValue(Letters.A)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("ControlDisplay")]
    [Description("Letter")]
    public Letters Letter { get; set; }


    public enum Letters
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }
}
```

[image]

Awesome :).

But I want to achieve this for a custom class or even a string.
How Should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the anwser (after digging some documentation - a lot of it).
First of all there is the `Type Converter` atribute
then a nice walktrought how to implement it is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx). [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afac5b07-3cd6-4a3c-9825-d488e9f8ec48/uitypeeditor-equivalent-in-wpf?forum=vswpfdesigner) is what led me to it.

In a nutshell:
Implement a type converter `GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)` to return true and `GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)` to return the `StandardValuesCollection` for the property type.
Finally just decorate the property like so:

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
    public MyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
```

The designer property window will now have a dropdown with valid values.